# Create a Flex4 component to have the typewriter effect in text

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

How can I create a Create a Flex4 component to have the typewriter effect in text , like shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usdJOktU-Gk)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom component based on Group.  Within that Group have a RichText component to display your text.  Add a text property to your custom component that, when set, starts a timer.  At each tick of the timer, take another character from the text property and add it to the text property of your RichText component.  Hope that helps.